# How to interact with a dynamically added swing component?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

The following code snippet will create a new Button when "button" is pressed. I'm wondering if there's any way to assign a name, Action Listener, or any other properties to this new button in order to use it.

```
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            panel.add(new JButton("Hello"));
            frame.revalidate();
            frame.repaint();
        }
    });
```

Example of what I'm looking for: On button press, create a new button that has a name and has an action performed when its clicked on. (Preferably I could dynamically make more than one button when clicked multiple times)

Comment: What is the end purpose of all these dynamically created buttons? What should happen if the user activates the 3rd? The 7th? See also [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a call of test(); into the actionPerformed() of your first button.

Every click on the first button will dynamicly create another button and name it individually. Every of these buttons also can dynamicly create individually named buttons.

```
//The counter is used to name the buttons individually
//It doesn´t matter wich of the created buttons will call test()
//any new button will have a different name than the other buttons
public int counter;    

public void test() {    
        JButton btn = new JButton();
        //Now you can edit the properties
        //btn.setLocation
        //btn.setSize
        //btn.setVisible
        //btn...
        btn.setText("Hello");
        btn.setName("Button" + counter);
        panel.add(btn);   

        //Add of listener is untested, but it should work like this
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
            @Override  
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                test();
            }
        });

        counter ++;
    }
```

Comment: While this is a great example of Buttons, I'm asking if its at all possible to create a NEW Button (Dynamically named) in the actionPerformed function of btn.

Comment: Just put a call of test() into the actionPerformed of the first button

Comment: For naming dynamicly you should use like a global counter or so

Comment: That would run another method yes, but as the coder I'm unsure whether or not the button will ever be pressed or how many times it will be pressed. I need a way to dynamically create, if necessary, multiple buttons all with different names.

Comment: On click of any buttons (the first one, or one of the dynamicly created ones) will create another button with an individual name (Button[number of button]) if you want the code anything else to do I´m afraid that I don´t understand you

Comment: If the naming is the problems and you want other naming rules than numbers it will get more complicated but i´ts the same principle

Comment: I never knew you could dynamically name like that, could you perhaps leave one more comment explaining that? I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Sure. The name of a button (or control in general) is just a string stored bin the object of the button. So to create a unique name, I just added a counter that I put into tha name of the button. Since the counter will be increased after ever call of test() the buttons will be named `Button0, Button1, Button2, Button3, Button4 ...` (you just have to make sure you don´t give other controls a name from that name pool and don´t create so many buttons that the Max_Value of int is reached)

Comment: @A. Johnson If my solution is what you were looking for, please mark the answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the `JButton` first:

```
JButton but = new JButton();
but.setText("Button");
```

Then add the listener. Inside the overriden `actionPerformed()` implement the actions to happen when you click on the button:

```
but.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Actions
    }
});
```

Finally add to the panel:

```
panel.add(but);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do this:

```
  JTextField textfield= new JTextField();

  button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {   
                JButton btn=new JButton();
                btn.setText(textfield.getText().toString());
                textfield.setText("");
                btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                             @Override
                             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                                    //the action on the button

                                    }
                             });   
                panel.add(btn);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Wouldn't that throw some sort of error having nested Action Listeners? Also, if the button was pressed more than once it would try to create multiple buttons named the same? Is there anyway to dynamically name and create buttons using a similar format to this?

Comment: @A.Johnson Not it will not throw an exception for nested Listners for any type. Also if you want dynamic naming for the button you can always use a textfield and add it to your frame and get the the new name from the textfield and set it to the button, see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, with use of **AbstractAction**:

```
Icon myIcon = null;
JButton btn = new JButton(new AbstractAction("ClickMe", myIcon) {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JOptionPane.showInputDialog("hello");
   }
});
panel.add(btn);
```

Cheers!